# No package 'libwebp' found: Package requirements (libwebp >= 0.2.0) were not met

Tags: php, docker, debian

I'm trying to build a Docker image for a **PHP** project with debian OS base image.

When I run the `Dockerfile` I get the error below:

```
checking for libwebp >= 0.2.0... no
configure: error: Package requirements (libwebp >= 0.2.0) were not met:

No package 'libwebp' found
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Here's how I solved it**:

All I needed to do was to add the dependency for it which was `libwebp-dev`:

I installed it this way:

```
RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y libwebp-dev \
  && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* \
```